# Welcome File List JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

In my welcome File list I have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">


<display-name>TP1</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>    
    <welcome-file>saisie_deb_animal.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!--  ServletFormulaire : -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Choix_animal</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>clinique.Choix_animal</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Supprime_animal</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>clinique.Supprime_animal</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<!-- Mapping ServletFormulaire : -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Choix_animal</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Choix_animal</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Supprime_animal</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Supprime_animal</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The application should start with the page saisie_deb_animal.html but for a reason I don't understand it keeps starting with formulaire.html, which exists within the WEB-INF directory but isn't used in my application.

Comment: What url are you trying to access and expecting `saisie_deb_animal.html`?

Comment: What server are you using? I know some servers expect a `/` in front of the welcome file

Comment: @Kevin: please don't confuse "welcome file" with "homepage file". The welcome file represents the sole filename of the file sitting in a folder which should be served up when a particular folder is been requested in URL without any filename, such as `http://example.com/`, `http://example.com/foo/`, `http://example.com/foo/bar/`, etc. If the welcome file is e.g. `index.html` and each of those folders contains such a file, then it will be served up instead of ending up in a 404.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I am using Apache Tomcat v7.0 Server

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I don't try to access any URL, I am running my application on the server Tomcat v7.0 I have added on eclipse

Comment: @akari What address are you trying to put in the browser?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Now I'm just using http://localhost:9081/TP1/

Comment: Have you noticed that there is a mix in XSD versions (2.5 and 3.0) in the root element? I'd suggest you fix that, it may create surprizes!

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos The `web` namespace is never used. It's just a label where it is specified.

Comment: could you post the saisie_deb_animal.html content for us to see?

Comment: can you check the saisie_deb_animal.html is redirecting to the file in WEB-INF folder

Comment: Stop your server, remove all applications, clean the server and the work directory, run the server without any app, stop it, add your app again and start the server, webtools things... you can check yourworkspacefolder\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core server content too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which exists within the WEB-INF directory but isn't used in my
>   application

This was the problem:
The WEB-INF/ directory contains a Web archive's private files and directories. That is, when the Web archive is deployed, the files and directories under the WEB-INF/ directory cannot be accessed directly by Web clients.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know because another file is called, but to call a file the url need start with /. If your url no starts with / an Servlet is called.

```
<welcome-file-list>    
    <welcome-file>/saisie_deb_animal.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```